# Getting MDB2 to work with sqlite3 via pdo

Tags: php, macos, sqlite, pear, mdb2

I am using [MDB2_Driver_pdoSqlite](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=6907#1236520724) to access a sqlite3 database with PEAR. I am able to connect to the database and display a list of tables with `listTables()`, but when I try to run the mdb2 function `tableInfo()` I get an error. `MDB2 Error: not found` `[Error message: primary is not an existing table constraint]` I am running the following system:

- MacOS X 10.5.8
- PHP 5.3.0
- sqlite 3.6.23.1
- MDB2 2.5.0b2
- MDB2 PDO SQLite3 driver v1

Any idea on what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the author and he told me his driver doesn't support primary keys. Once I removed the primary key fields from my tables it worked. So I think I will try out [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) to get php database abstraction.